# TableView AccessoryType Checkmark shuffles

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have 2 sections in my tableView and have multipleSelection as true.
If I select 1st cell in section one and then scroll down then 2nd section's 1st cell is already selected and on some random scroll is shuffled.

Also I don't have any code written in cellForRowAt to mark `checkmark`

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you use `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` to get your cell in `cellForRow(at:)`
Let's say initially you have 10 visible Cells in your TableView. If you now scroll up, and `cellForRow(at:)` is called for the next cell then a new cell is created (as the recycle pool is empty) and added to the bottom of the TableView. As soon as the cell at the top disappears from the screen it will be added to the recycle pool. If you know scroll further up, then again `cellForRow(at:)` is called and in side of ti `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)`is called. But now instead of creating a new cell, the next cell will be taken out of the recycle pool and this cell will be added to the bottom.
If you don't change the value of a property, it will keep the values before it had been added to the recycle pool.
You should either reset the cell to default values in `prepareForReuse()` of your `UITableViewCell` subclass or check and set all values in `cellForRow(at:)`

Answer (score 0):

you can try new `UITableViewCell` class, add a new variable for example
 `var isSelect: Bool = false`.
you can in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` judgment `isSelect` 's value do the corresponding display processing, when you did select tableView, change this cell's `isSelect` and `reloadData()`. sorry, my English is not good, the expression may not be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Cell will be reused by tableview.You should use a array model or dictionary model to mark selected status. like this:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      selectedArray[indexPath.row] = true 
      tableView.reload()
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      selectedArray[indexPath.row] = false
      tableView.reload()
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //init cell
     let selected = selectedArray[indexPath.row]
     cell.accessoryType =  selected ? .checkmark : .none
}
```

Comment: @simalome Is it correct way to reload tableView on each select/deselect ?

Comment: just it is simple :). you can use 'tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexpath], with: .none)' instead will be better.